# Reset AJAX/Modal data (PHP Codeigniter)

Tags: javascript, php

So im cloning a table and populating it in this javascript with the data I got using AJAX.
The problem is that this function runs 'onClick' and, the data doesn't get reset, instead it appends the old cloned table with the newly cloned ones. How can I reset it? every time I click.

Here is the 'onClick' button/function:

```
    <table class="table-hover table dashboard">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <!-- <th id="request-id">ID</th> -->
                <th id="request-name">NAME</th>
                <th id="requestor-name">OWNER</th>
                <th id="urgency">URGENCY</th>
                <th id="request-date">EXPORTATION DATE</th>
                <th id="environment">ENVIRONMENT</th>
                <th id="status">STATUS</th>
                <!-- <th id="actions">ACTIONS</th> -->
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="data">
            <?php foreach($shared_requests as $request){ ?>
                <tr onclick="this.onclick = view_project('<?php echo $request->projectID; ?>', '<?php echo $request->taskID; ?>', '<?php echo $request->requestID; ?>')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view_request">
                    <td class="txt-oflo" id="request-name">PROD_CR-csremail-au-wiscust-au-PO(B2BE#3893292)</td>
                    <td class="txt-oflo" id="requestor-name"><?php echo $request->owner ;?></td>
                    <td class="txt-oflo" id="urgency">NORMAL</td>
                    <td class="txt-oflo" id="request-date"><?php echo $request->requestDate ;?></td>
                    <td class="txt-oflo" id="environment"><?php echo $request->environment ;?></td>
                    <td class="txt-oflo" id="status"><?php echo $request->status ;?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here is my AJAX:

```
function view_project(projectID, taskID, requestID) {
        var projectID = projectID;
        var taskID = taskID;
        var requestID = requestID;
        var json = {'projectID':'" + projectID + "','taskID':'" + taskID + "','requestID':'" + requestID + "'};
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:"<?php echo site_url('request/view_request'); ?>/" + projectID + "/" + taskID + "/" + requestID,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: json,
            success:function(data) {
                console.log(data.requests);
                console.log(data.curr_request);
                console.log(data.translation_changes);
                console.log(data.translations);

                //Project Details
                document.getElementById("projectID").innerHTML = data.curr_request[0]['projectID'];
                document.getElementById("taskID").innerHTML = data.curr_request[0]['taskID'];
                document.getElementById("projectOwner").innerHTML = data.curr_request[0]['projectOwner'];
                document.getElementById("docType").innerHTML = data.curr_request[0]['docType'];
                document.getElementById("sender").innerHTML = data.curr_request[0]['sender'];
                document.getElementById("receiver").innerHTML = data.curr_request[0]['receiver'];

                var requestsNum = Object.keys(data.requests).length;
                var translationNum = Object.keys(data.translations).length;

                //Translation Changes
                for(var i = 0; i < requestsNum; i++){
                    //Cloning (Per Revision)
                    if(i != 0){
                        var cloneRevision = $('#revisions').clone(true)
                        .insertAfter(".revisions:last")
                        .attr("id", "revisions" + i);

                        cloneRevision.find('[id]').each(function() {
                            var strNewId = $(this).attr('id').replace(/[0-9]/g, i);
                            $(this).attr('id', strNewId);
                            $(this).attr('name', strNewId);
                        });
                    }

                    //Mapping
                    document.getElementById("revisionNumber["+i+"]").innerHTML = data.requests[i]['revisionNumber'];
                    document.getElementById("requestDate["+i+"]").innerHTML = data.requests[i]['requestDate'];
                    document.getElementById("deployDate["+i+"]").innerHTML = data.requests[i]['deployDate']; 
                    document.getElementById("environment["+i+"]").innerHTML = data.requests[i]['environment'];
                    document.getElementById("status["+i+"]").innerHTML = data.requests[i]['status'];                   

                    for(var j = 0; j < translationNum; j++){
                        //Cloning (Per translation)
                        if(data.requests[i]['requestID'] + data.translations[j]['requestID']){
                            if(j != 0){
                                var cloneTranslation = $('#translations').clone(true)
                                .insertAfter(".translations:last")
                                .attr("id", "translations" + j);

                                cloneTranslation.find('[id]').each(function() {
                                    var NewID = $(this).attr('id').replace(/[0-9]/g, j);
                                    $(this).attr('id', NewID);
                                    $(this).attr('name', NewID);
                                });
                            }           

                            //Mapping              
                            document.getElementById("changes["+j+"]").innerHTML = data.translation_changes[j]['changes'];
                            document.getElementById("name["+j+"]").innerHTML = data.translations[j]['name'];
                            document.getElementById("internalID["+j+"]").innerHTML = data.translations[j]['internalID'];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

This is what im cloning:

```
<div class="container view-request">
<table class="revisions table table-bordered" id="revisions">
    <thead class="header">
        <tr class="header text-dark">
            <th colspan="4" class="text-center">
                REVISION <span id="revisionNumber[0]"></span>
                <span><span id="status[0]"></span> to <span id="environment[0]"></span></span>
            </th>
        <tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody class="translations" id="translations">
        <tr>
            <th>Request Date</th>
            <td id="requestDate[0]"></td>
            <th>Deployment Date</th>
            <td id="deployDate[0]"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Test Internal ID:</strong> </td>
            <td id="internalID[0]"></td>
            <th colspan="">Release as Document Type:</th>
            <td id="doctype[0]"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Translation Name:</th>
            <td id="name[0]"></td>  
            <th>Translation Changes</th>
            <td id="changes[0]" colspan="3"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="spacer"><td colspan="4"></td></tr>   
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Basically what im trying to do is reset the clones. I can't seem to find a way how. Is there any? :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: before cloning set the html as blank , if it is repeating itself

Comment: It is a little hard to understand what you are asking.  `... instead it appends the old cloned table with the newly cloned ones` ... that sort of seems the entire point of your code, AFAICT?  To continually add tables with newly retrieved data to the page. Do you mean that everything should disappear and start from scratch, so all the clones should disappear each click?

Comment: PS - there is a lot of code here, and at least some of it seems unrelated to the problem at hand (eg `#projectID` stuff).  It would be a *lot* easier for us to grok and help if you could reduce it to a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - eg surely a single `<tr><td></td></tr>` would be enough to demonstrate the problem?